# Using GeoServer and OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am new to using GIS and struggling to insert one of my layers that I uploaded in GeoServer in an OpenLayers 3 map. Unfortunately, I do not get the layer displayed.

Can you help me fix the problem?

See attached my code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Image ({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS ({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms', 
        params: {
          'LAYERS':'cite:SWE_adm2'
        }
      }),
      ratio: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ([55.11, 13.82]),
    zoom: 4,
  })
});
```

Comment: What are the available projections for the WMS? The map projection you use? Why do you use `ratio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only hint as you do not provide enough information

- `ratio` and `serverType` must be in the source not in the `ol.layer.Image` (See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html)